# Compare two files and print exact match in the order of input file

Tags: python

I have scenario where I have two files.
file 1 has the following values

```
192.168.1.1/32
192.168.1.11/32
172.16.18.30/24
```

and file 2 has the following values

```
192.168.1.1/32 XYZ
10.0.0.10/32 IP-3  
172.16.18.30/24 IP-2
```

I wanted a python script which will check the exact value of file 1 against file2 and if that values are present in file2 it should be displayed. I created a basic script which seems to be working but the output is displayed in Alphabetical order rather than the order of lines in file1.

Below is the script I have.

```
with open("file1.txt") as f, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    src = set(map(str.rstrip,f))
    for line in f2:
        dst = line.split(None, 1)[0]
        if dst in src:
            print(line.rstrip())
```

The current output will be in order:

```
172.16.18.30/24 IP-2 
192.168.1.1/32 XYZ
```

Is there a way to get the output in below order:

```
192.168.1.1/32 XYZ
172.16.18.30/24 IP-2
```

Comment: Please describe the **relevant part** of the input clearly, and the desired output clearly.

Comment: I have updated it the question a little bit. Is it still not clear?

Comment: It is now......

Comment: I just copy-pasted everything from your question (no modifications) and ran the script it prints in the desired (and expected) order. I don't understand why you're seeing the lines out of order.

Comment: Hi can you change the following in File1 with
74.6.143.26/32
151.101.193.67/32

and file2 with
151.101.128.81 bbc.com
151.101.193.67/32 cnn.com
142.250.181.46/32 google.com
74.6.143.26/32 yahoo.com

and check the output

Answer (score 0):

Using `any` and a list comprehension does a pretty nice job of handling this.

```
>>> file1_lines = [
...   "192.168.1.1/32",
...   "192.168.1.11/32",
...   "172.16.18.30/24"
... ]
>>>
>>> file2_lines = [
...   "192.168.1.1/32 XYZ",
...   "10.0.0.10/32 IP-3",
...   "172.16.18.30/24 IP-2"
... ]
>>>
>>> [line for line in file2_lines if any(l in line for l in set(file1_lines))]
['192.168.1.1/32 XYZ', '172.16.18.30/24 IP-2']
>>>
```

That does not handle the ordering.

```
>>> for f1_line in set(file1_lines):
...     for f2_line in file2_lines:
...         if f1_line in f2_line:
...             print(f2_line)
...
192.168.1.1/32 XYZ
172.16.18.30/24 IP-2
>>>
```

To avoid duplication:

```
d = []

for f2_line in file2_lines:
    found = None
    for f1_line in set(file1_lines):
        if f1_line in f2_line:
            found = f1_line
            break
    if found:
        d.append({'key': found, 'line': f2_line})
        
for f1_line in file1_lines:
    for h in d:
        if h['key'] == f1_line:
            print(h['line'])
```

We'll tag each line from file 2 with a `'key'` that is the line in file 1 that it contains. When we're done, we can iterate over lines in file 1, and use them to find all of the lines from file 2 that they matched.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this in sometime and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried this but it creates problems when there are duplicate values and the list with me very large like approximately 3000 lines in file2.

Comment: It's possible that if a line in the first file is contained within another line, you may get duplicates.

Comment: Edited to address that issue.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I will test it out.